# Whats wrong in the following cpp Bucubic interpolation code for Image Resizing

Tags: image-processing, opencv, interpolation, bicubic

I am trying to upsample an Image using Bicubic Interpoloation, I need the accurate values matching the cvResize() function of opencv, but the results of following code is not matching the results from cvResize(), can you take a look and help me to fix the bug.

```
Image *Image::resize_using_Bicubic(int w, int h) {
    float dx,dy;
    float x,y;
    float tx, ty;
    float i,j,m,n;
```

`Image *result=new Image(w, h);
tx = (float)this->m_width/(float)w;
ty = (float)this->m_height/(float)h;
for(i=0; i< w; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j< h; j++)
    {
        x = i*tx;
        y = j*ty;
        dx = float(i-x)-(int)(i-x);
        dy = float(j-y)-(int)(j-y);
        float temp=0.0;
        for(m=-1;m<=2;m++)
        {
            for(n=-1;n<=2;n++)
            { 

                int HIndex,WIndex;
                HIndex=(y+n);
                WIndex=(x+m);

                if (HIndex<0) {
                    HIndex=0;
                }
                else if(HIndex>this->getHeight())
                {
                    HIndex=this->getHeight()-1;

                }
                if (WIndex<0) {
                    WIndex=0;
                }
                else if(WIndex>this->getWidth())
                {
                    WIndex=this->getWidth()-1;

                }


                temp+=this->getPixel(HIndex,WIndex)*R(m-dx)*R(dy-n);
            }
        }

        result->setPixel(j, i, temp);
    }
}
return result;`

}

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said how different the results are. If they're very close, say within 1 or 2 in each RGB channel, this could be explained simply by roundoff differences.

There is more than one algorithm for Bicubic interpolation. Don Mitchell and Arun Netravali did an analysis and came up with a single formula to describe a number of them: http://www.mentallandscape.com/Papers_siggraph88.pdf

**Edit:** One more thing, the individual filter coefficients should be summed up and used to divide the final value at the end, to normalize the values. And I'm not sure why you have `m-dx` for one and `dy-n` for the other, shouldn't they be the same sign?

```
r=R(m-dx)*R(dy-n);
r_sum+=r;
temp+=this->getPixel(HIndex,WIndex)*r;
. . .
result->setPixel(j, i, temp/r_sum);
```

Comment: The image data is single channel grayscale data and i have divided the each value by 255. Till resize the values are matching with opencv, and after resize cvResize values are like 0.289782 0.291181 0.294753 0.302059. . . and the results of above function are as 0.292048 0.294635 0.298366 0.302356. . . My requirement is to implement SIFT algorithm without using opencv, so this small variation is affecting the later stages of the algorithm.

Comment: You may be handling edges differently than OpenCV does - try checking some values which are not within the image border.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
            else if(HIndex>this->getHeight())
```

to:

```
            else if(HIndex >= this->getHeight())
```

and change:

```
            else if(WIndex>this->getWidth())
```

to:

```
            else if(WIndex >= this->getWidth())
```

**EDIT**

Also change:

```
    for(m=-1;m<=2;m++)
    {
        for(n=-1;n<=2;n++)
```

to:

```
    for(m = -1; m <= 1; m++)
    {
        for(n = -1; n <= 1; n++)
```

Comment: The changed those lines of code but there is no difference:-(

Comment: You probably have more bugs in the code, but at least these two bugs are fixed now. See also two more bug fixes which I've added to the answer above.